# AngularJS to Angular 15 migration

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs

I am trying to run angularjs and angular 15 in hybrid mode, getting the below error when trying to import angularjs main module into angular

[image]

- Tried importing the main angularjs module after bootstrapping in app.component.js
- Want both angularjs and angular run side by side.
- getting import errors and app.module.js